# How to enforce https protocol for all the default repositories (regardless of their configuration)?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to use SBT behind a firewall that blocks all HTTP responses of type "application/java-archive".  However, I see that it doesn't block if the request is made using HTTPS, and it appears that the Typesafe and Maven repositories do support HTTPS connections.  Is there a way to configure SBT to access all of its default repositories using "https://" instead of "http://"?

It looks like the "proxy repository" configuration might be one way to accomplish this, but I wasn't sure of the full list of default repositories to be replaced, or of the exact syntax of the "~/.sbt/repositories" file that would accomplish this.  A complete working example of this approach, or an alternate solution, would make SBT much easier to use in restricted environments.  Thanks in advance.

(And just to clarify: I am not trying to set up or use a proxy; I just want to use https to access the normal servers.)